# Java first GUI, two classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I'm trying to program my first GUI-class in Java, using the Window Builder. Ok, the GUI is ready but has no functions yet (it contains 10 checkboxes (yes, they are all neccessary) and 2 buttons and a JTextField, so nothing special). So I just drag'n'dropped the checkboxes and button into the window, I haven't coded anything yet.

I have two classes:
GUI.java -> only for the layout
Main.java -> should get 'inputs' from GUI.java

Now the user should check or uncheck the checkboxes and then finally press a button.

But how do I 'read out' if a checkbox is checked or not - I have two classes?

I have to add that I'm a beginner to Java and especially to GUI-programming, but I just want to learn it. I would be happy to receive some help but NOT the complete code.

Comment: you should probably pick an answer since there are plenty of good ones, or at the least give a few votes up for the people who took time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you didn't want the full, code but this isn't really it, just a very basic working demo of what you want to do

[image]

**Gui.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui {
JFrame frame;
JButton button;
JCheckBox checkBox;
JLabel label;

public Gui() {
    frame = new JFrame("demo");
    button = new JButton("is it checked?");
    checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    label = new JLabel("no");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(checkBox);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    //frame.setSize(200, 60);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// method to add an action listener to the gui's
// private button
public void setButtonActionListener(ActionListener al) {
    button.addActionListener(al);
}

// gui method to check if box is checked
public boolean isBoxChecked() {
    return checkBox.isSelected();
}

// method to set lable
public void setText(String text) {
    label.setText(text);
}

}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create an instance of your gui class
    final Gui gui = new Gui();

    // add the action listener to the button
            // notice how we reference the gui here by running the methods in the
            // gui class
            // this action listener could be created in the gui
            // class but in general you don't want to do that because actions will 
            // involve multiple classes
    gui.setButtonActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            gui.setText((gui.isBoxChecked() ? "yes" : "no"));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I (basically) know how to use an ActionListener, my problem is how to use the checkboxes from GUI.java in Main.java.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you instantiate an object of your GUI from the Main.java. Then you have access to this GUI (assumed you have setter/getter-methods or the Components in the GUI are public). In the GUI constructor you call all builder methods, so when you then call `new GUI()` from Main.java, you got a) the GUI running and b) access to it from Main.java

For your specific question about the checkboxes, you can call

```
nameOfCheckbox.isSelected()
```

which returns a boolean wheter the checkbox is checked or not.

Viceversa: since your Main.java has (or should have) static methods (like the main-method), you can then simply call `Main.anyMethodName()` from GUI.java (assuming this anyMethod is `static`) and pass data from the "visual area" to the "logic area" (it is recommended to seperate this two componentes as good as possible).

Comment: No, I haven't got any setter-/getter-methods yet in my GUI cause I' quite unsure about that. Which getter-/setter-methods are necessary?

Comment: This is depending on what you want to do... Let's say you want to change some text in the checkboxes, you should have a public method `public CheckBox getCheckboxXY(){...}`, so you can "pass" that Objet from GUI to Main and set a new text with `setText(String xy)`. But this is not necessary if you let's say just want to pass data from GUI to Main, and not viceversa. Like I mentioned, if you want to pass the selected items to Main to do further work, you simply create a static method in Main, which can be called from GUI

Comment: After the user presses the button the program should check which checkboxes are checked and write them into a file. I know how to generate the file and how to fill it, but I don't know anything about GUI-programming.

Comment: write to a file or pass it to Main.java to do further work? If you want to write to a file, you should read first [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: So you could add an ActionListener to the button, and in there you could say (assuming you exposed the gui components with get() methods): if (gui.getCheckBox1().isSelected()) ... for each of your check boxes

Comment: Valentino: at first I want to pass it to Main.java, then write into the file. The first part of this contains my problem. @user12345613: no, I havent't exposed anything yet.

Comment: so you first make it like user12345613 said, set an ItemListener on the Button which checks all Checkboxes and does the work you want to. Then you call (still in that ItemListener) a static method, which you defined in Main.java like described above. There you can write the things you need in a file. For beginning with Java I/O i recommend to read the link I posted, it is very useful to understand the structures of the input- and output-streams

Answer (score 0):

Attach an `ItemListener`.

You can determine if the box is rising (unchecked to checked) or falling (checked to unchecked) with the following line in `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)`

```
boolean selected = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
```

To determine whether it is checked when it is not changing, just use `isSelected()`

Answer (score 0):

Either like that:

```
checkbox.isSelected();
```

Or this would be a way by an Itemlistener which will be called if there is a change:

```
checkbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                foo = false;

            } else {
                foo = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expose all of your gui objects as fields in your gui class

```
public JTextField getNameTextField() {
    return nameTextField;
}

public JCheckBox getCheckBox1() {
    return checkBox1;
}
```

and then in main:

```
if (gui.getCheckBox1().isSelected())
    // do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me! Is this the object-orientation-part of Java (I think so?). So I have to do this for all checkboxes, buttons and so on and then check the status in Main.java?

Comment: I guess this is under the category of object oriented. You have a class whose only job is to render a gui on screen. It also provides other classes with the ability to receive notification when something happens to the gui (a check box is clicked, text entered into a JTextField, etc) by exposing the components as properties and letting other classes attach Listener objects to them. The other class (main in your case) has the sole job of doing the back end logic when something happens to the gui. Google MVC pattern in java - that is one design pattern commonly used.

Comment: @user131 I wouldn't put a getter on the `JCheckBox` itself, unless you plan to do some modifications on the checkbox from Main.java (which doesn't sound like what you want), but rather do a `isCheckBox1Checked()` method that returns `checkBox1.isSelected()`

Comment: @gobernador I guess it all depends - if he has 12 check boxes and wants information on various properties from a controller class, i think having a getter for the whole widget is easier than exposing the various members of the widget itself.

Comment: you would have a get method for each thing you want to make available to outside classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your checkbox is an object named "myCheckBox", you can check if it's selected or not by using:

```
myCheckBox.isSelected()
```

Returns true if the checkbox is selected.

I reccomend you to check Java's tutorials on how to use the various GUI components, e.g:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: @user1318160 (Not trying to be rude, I promise) If you don't know what an object is you should read some beginner's book/tutorial before proceeding.

Comment: Maybe my question seems very 'stupid', but I'd really like to learn to programm and I'd like to do this with this little project. You're right, I have to look for a good book. Can you recommend any?

Comment: @user1318160 Sadly no. The book I used wasn't very good. There are some suggestions [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-java-books-websites-etc) though (that thread recommends _Head First Java_). I'd recommend that you don't dive into this project though. It will slow down the learning process.